# Migrating from Google Sign-In and Google Classroom

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-classroom

I'm currently trying to add google sign-in support to our educational website. The majority of time users will just sign in with Google, but occasionally teachers need to be able to import pupil rosters from Google Classroom too.  I've got all of this working using the guides from the Classroom developers site (https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js). I'm using https://apis.google.com/js/api.js to sign users in (gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn) with just the "profile" scope and then  granting the extra classroom scopes if teachers need them.

I'm just reading the Migrating to Google Sign-In guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) and trying to work out if it applies to us or not.  It's explicitly saying not to use gapi.auth2/gapi.client etc anymore and to use the new Identity Services Library instead, but there's no explanation how to use that to make API calls to Classroom (or any other Google API).  The OAuth 2.0 JS guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) is still saying to use gapi.auth2 etc too.

So should I be using the new library to sign users in, instead of api.js?

And if so, am I still supposed to be using gapi.auth2 to make API calls, or should I be using the new library instead somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication for sign-in, and authorization for data access are being separated. Use the new Identity Services library for sign-in instead of api.js and the profile scope. This should be the case for the majority of your users based upon what you've shared.

Later, and as needed, continue using gapi.auth2 to obtain an access token and call the Classroom or other Google APIs.

Functionally, what this will look like is separating out your sign-in flow using HTML or JavaScript from gapi.auth2 and access/refresh tokens.  Token requests for calling APIs (using either implicit or auth code) would be made only at the point they're needed. Say you'll use 3 different scopes at some point, each would be requested only when necessary, also known as [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#incrementalAuth).